# How does OpenGL Communicate with the GPU?

Tags: c, opengl, operating-system

OpenGL is an interface to perform graphical commands. Now, if the library is multi-platform how does it interact with the GPU is it by making system calls and thus making it multi-platform or does it use drivers to perform its operations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OpenGL is typically implemented as part of the *graphics drivers*. Each implementation will use implementation-specific interfaces to talk to some kernel-space component and the real HW.

One can see a bit more how these things might be done by looking at the [MESA](http://mesa3d.org) based open-source GL implementation on Linux. They actually use the [DRM](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DRM/) (direct rendering manager) API of the Linux kernel to talk to the HW. MESA's current implementation is organised such that for each GPU, there is a drm kernel driver and a user-space DRI client. Mesa now uses the [gallium](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gallium/) API as an abstraction layer to keep the GPU-specifc code small and make it more portable. The OpenGL API is implemented on top of that as a "state tracker:, and is independent of the GPU drivers. (There even has been a [D3D10/11 state tracker](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/commit/?id=92617aeac109481258f0c3863d09c1b8903d438b), but it was more like a test and was later removed because it became unmaintained.)

The fact that OpenGL is defined as a plaform-independent *API* does not mean that the *OpenGL library* will be platform-independent at all. This is the same situation as with the C library API is part of the language standard, but the implementation is very platform-specific.

Comment: Your last paragraph says a lot. Thank you for that. I always wondered how a platform-independent library could also be dependent on the system. Great answer thank you very much. Would vote you up but I can't yet.